# If $\gamma\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous and $\gamma(b)=-\gamma(a)$, must the curves $\gamma$ and $e^{ic}\gamma$ intersect for all real $c$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, plane-curves

If $[a, b]$ is a compact interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and
$\gamma: [a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, denote the connected,
compact set $\gamma([a, b])$ by $[\gamma]$. If $h$ is a complex
number of unit modulus, define the curve
$h\gamma \colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ by
$(h\gamma)(t) = h(\gamma(t))$. (If $h = -1$, write $h\gamma$ as $-\gamma$.)

> If $\gamma(b) = -\gamma(a)$, must we have $[\gamma] \cap [h\gamma] \ne \emptyset$?

This trivially true for $h = \pm1$, and it has been proved (although not
easily) for $h = \pm i$. We can assume without loss of generality
that $h = e^{ic}$, where $0 < c < \pi$.

The [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106208)
for the case $h = \pm i$ was first asked by
Herman Tulleken, with the proviso that an answer was allowed to make
almost arbitrary special assumptions about $\gamma$, subject only to
applicability to a particular problem related to polyominoes.

Accordingly, @YiFan asked the
[question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109299) again,
still for the case
$h = \pm i$, but this time only specifying that $\gamma$ is
injective (and of course continuous), but should otherwise be
arbitrary.  @Jens observed, in a comment on this question, that the
result seemed to be true for a general rotation, not just
$90^\circ$.

I had made the same comment on the first question, not knowing that
a second question had been asked - but I have also made many badly
mistaken comments on both questions!

Although my judgement on this problem is evidently suspect, I am
fairly confident of the validity of Hagen von Eitzen's answer to the
second question, and even of my own answer to it.  Both answers
(independently) use the same construction, which is to concatenate
$\gamma$ with $-\gamma$, forming a closed curve; it is then
necessary to argue that if $z$ belongs to $[\gamma] \cup [-\gamma]$
and $[i\gamma] \cup [-i\gamma]$, then one of $\pm z, \pm iz$ belongs
to $[\gamma] \cap [i\gamma]$. My initial vague impression that both
arguments could handle the case of a general rotation seems, sadly,
to be just another mistake.

Neither of these answers to the second question used the assumption
of injectivity, so the case $h = \pm i$ (equivalently, w.l.o.g.,
$c = \frac{\pi}{2}$) seems to be settled.

The evidence for the general case is admittedly weak.  I don't find
it intuitively obvious (even though I keep kidding myself that I
glimpse "reasons" why it should be true). The mere fact that it
holds for $h = \pm i$ is not compelling.  Beyond this, I only have
the conviction gained from doing simple experiments with GeoGebra:
creating $\gamma$ as a polyline object, moving the vertices around,
and observing the intersections with one or more rotated copies.

Nevertheless, for what it's worth, I feel quite strongly that the general result
is true.  I also feel, slightly less strongly, that it probably has
a simple proof using only elementary results about continuity.  I
don't think that anything as deep as the Jordan Curve Theorem is
needed.  Even my proof for the case $h = \pm i$ (which is short, if
you allow the use of a lemma that seems to be of more general use)
is probably more complex than the "Book" proof of the general
result.

However, if no elementary proof is forthcoming, I will accept an
answer using advanced methods.  I won't be competent to judge such
an answer myself, but I will happily take advice (in a chatroom, if
there isn't space in the comments).

Comment: Looks like this one problem sparked $4$ questions!

Comment: The answer by Hagen von Eitzen to the other question relies on the fact that intersection of the closed paths implies intersection of the original curve and copy, which only follows if the rotation is 90 degrees. We could preserve this if we change the construction from $\gamma$ to $\tilde{\gamma}$ to use a reflection instead of a 180 rotation. I have not checked if the rest of the proof still works in this case.

Comment: I mean a reflection about the line trough $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$. (But like I said, I have not tried testing it properly.)

Comment: 0.o yes I commented too quickly. (Furthermore, it also looks like even if that part _did_ work we would not have the Jordan curve positioned such that we can prove paths cannot escape from 0 so the whole thing falls flat there too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by your counterexample, here's a counterexample with the rotation angle less than $90^\circ$:

[image]

Seems my intuition was wrong.

Comment: My flabber is quite gasted.

Comment: Nice :) I managed to construct counterexamples using this idea for 50 and 35 degrees... but have not been able to do 45 degrees... and I am wondering whether that may be impossible. (Quite likely I just did not try long enough.)

Comment: (Oh I just saw the edits to the other answer now.)

Answer (score 6):

No - but I'll stubbornly carry on trying to prove it for $|c| \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}$.

It was from work on a promising-looking idea for a proof that this embarrassing counterexample emerged -

[image: Counterexample with c = \frac{3\pi}{4}.]

---

Following on from Jens's *coup de grâce*, I haven't yet been
able to find a counterexample for a rotation by $\frac{\pi}{3}$,
$\frac{\pi}{4}$, or $\frac{\pi}{5}$.

In logarithmic polar coordinates (with $\theta$ increasing to
the right, and $\log r$ increasing either up or down, it doesn't
matter which), mimicking Jens's example for an angle between
$\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, it was easy to construct a
counterexample for $\frac{9\pi}{40}$, lying between
$\frac{\pi}{5}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$:

[image: Counterexample with c = \frac{5\pi}{40}.]

But this is what happened when I tried to do something similar for
$\frac{\pi}{5}$:

[image: Failing to construct a counterexample with c = \frac{\pi}{5}.]

Here is a similarly unsuccessful attempt to construct a counterexample for
$c = \frac{\pi}{3}$:

[image: Failing to construct a counterexample with c = \frac{\pi}{3}.]

Can anyone find a counterexample with $c = \frac{\pi}{n}$, for any
positive integer $n$?

(As this is a Community Wiki post, anyone should feel free to
contribute pertinent observations.)

---

Here is a counterexample for 35 degrees, which is close to 36.)[image]

Comment: Good luck! your conjecture looks plausible.

Comment: Please do update this page if you make progress, I would be very interested to find out!

Comment: Nice counterexample!

Comment: As there may still be some life in this conjecture, I'll add that it isn't difficult to prove that if there is a counterexample for a particular value of $h$ (such as $e^{i\pi/n}$ for some positive integer $n$), then for the same value of $h$ there is a counterexample that is piecewise linear (either in Cartesian or logarithmic polar coordinates, whichever you prefer), so it is probably not a waste of time to play around with GeoGebra (or similar software) in search of counterexamples.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that the case of $\pi/n$ for positive integers $n$ would be more difficult? It seems to me like the difficulty of constructing such a counterexample would only depend on the size of the angle; am I wrong?

Comment: @YiFan I only have experimental evidence from playing with GeoGebra. I've been dead wrong about this problem on the basis of such evidence before. My experiments never seem to be done thoroughly enough, and I'll have to try to tighten up a bit before leaping to conclusions. That's why I'm holding back from asking yet another question on the same subject! It's not at all unlikely that someone will find a counterexample for some $\frac{\pi}{n}$.

Comment: I managed to construct counter-examples for 35 and 50 degrees quite quickly... but 45 degrees eluded me... so I agree that there is something going on more than just the size.

Comment: @HermanTulleken $50^\circ$ isn't surprising, but I'd love to see the $30^\circ$ example. (I hadn't got as far as trying $\frac{\pi}{6}$.) Can you insert it into this answer?

Comment: Sorry, it was 35. I try to convert it to 45 and lost it but let me try again.

Comment: It doesn't look as if $B'C'$ passes through the centre $A$ in any of the figures. Am I misreading them?

Comment: Geogebra does not work the way I thought, so all the examples where wrong. The 35 degrees one is valid though, so I added that for what it is worth. I removed the wrong images and comments.

Comment: @Calum I agree with you that counterexamples with rotation angles of $\frac{180^\circ}{n}$ don't seem possible. The problem, of course, is that in order to encompass the first "spike" at $0^\circ$ you need a spike at $\frac{180^\circ}{n}$, and in order to encompass that spike, you need a spike at $\frac{2*180^\circ}{n}$, etc, until you need one at $180^\circ$, which won't work. Ready to make a new question? :)

Comment: @Jens Your wish is my command! :) Future counterexamples may be posted as answers here: [Must a curve $\eta \colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ intersect
the curves $\eta + \frac{\eta(b) - \eta(a)}{n}$ ($n \geqslant 1$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125569).